# How to vectorize/parallelize or otherwise speed up these nested for loops in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, parallel-processing, vectorization

I'm new to the concept of parallelizing and vectorizing code, but my Matlab code is running extremely slowly and I am looking for a way to speed it up. Would either of these methods be a good fit here, and what is the best way to go about that? I have a relatively complicated nested for loop:

```
for ii = 1:4%length(is2roi) %This is for each crossover location
    for jj = 1:numsim+1 %this is for each velocity perturbation

        u = vel.e_vel(:,:,jj);
        v = vel.n_vel(:,:,jj);

        u_interp = inpaint_nans(u);
        v_interp = inpaint_nans(v);

        for  kk = 1:length(couplinglengthscale)

            %define the coupling lengthscale based on the grid
            gridcellcount =...
                            ceil((roithick(ii) .* couplinglengthscale(kk) )...
                            ./ vel.pixelsize);


            if gridcellcount > largeboundingboxsize
                disp('Coupling length is larger than the bounding box, Abort')
                return
            end

            % Define an initial bounding box for each IS2 ROI/crossover location before rotation using Vel_row and Ve_col index
            bottom   = [velrow(ii), velcol(ii) + (gridcellcount)];
            right    = [velrow(ii) + gridcellcount, velcol(ii)];
            left     = [velrow(ii) - gridcellcount, velcol(ii)];
            top      = [velrow(ii), velcol(ii) - (gridcellcount)];
            centloc  = [velrow(ii), velcol(ii)];

            Xpi      = [X(centloc(1), centloc(2)), X(top(1), top(2)),...
                X(right(1), right(2)), X(bottom(1), bottom(2)), X(left(1), left(2))];
            Ypi      = [Y(centloc(1), centloc(2)), Y(top(1), top(2)),...
                Y(right(1), right(2)), Y(bottom(1), bottom(2)), Y(left(1), left(2))];      
            
            a10      = sqrt((Xpi(5)-Xpi(1))^2+(Ypi(5)-Ypi(1))^2);
            a20      = sqrt((Xpi(4)-Xpi(1))^2+(Ypi(4)-Ypi(1))^2);
            b10      = sqrt((Xpi(5)-Xpi(2))^2+(Ypi(5)-Ypi(2))^2);
            b20      = sqrt((Xpi(4)-Xpi(3))^2+(Ypi(4)-Ypi(3))^2);
            c10      = sqrt((Xpi(2)-Xpi(1))^2+(Ypi(2)-Ypi(1))^2);
            c20      = sqrt((Xpi(3)-Xpi(1))^2+(Ypi(3)-Ypi(1))^2);
            d10      = sqrt((Xpi(4)-Xpi(2))^2+(Ypi(4)-Ypi(2))^2);
            d20      = sqrt((Xpi(5)-Xpi(3))^2+(Ypi(5)-Ypi(3))^2);

            halflength = a10; % l = a10 = a20 = c10 = c20;
            
            num_alphas = length(alphas);
            xpisave = zeros(5, num_alphas);
            ypisave = zeros(5, num_alphas);
            xpsave = zeros(5, num_alphas);
            ypsave = zeros(5, num_alphas);
            eresults = zeros(3, num_alphas);

            for mm = 1:num_alphas

                alpha   = alphas(mm);

                lof1    = halflength*cosd(alpha-90);
                lof2    = halflength*sind(alpha-90);

                Xpi     = [X(centloc(1), centloc(2)), (X(centloc(1),...
                    centloc(2)) -lof1), (X(centloc(1), centloc(2)) +lof1), (X(centloc(1), centloc(2)) +lof2), (X(centloc(1), centloc(2)) -lof2)];
                Ypi     = [Y(centloc(1), centloc(2)), (Y(centloc(1),...
                    centloc(2)) -lof2), (Y(centloc(1), centloc(2)) +lof2), (Y(centloc(1), centloc(2)) -lof1), (Y(centloc(1), centloc(2)) +lof1)];
                Xp      = Xpi;
                Yp      = Ypi;

                for nn = 1:nt

                    % Integrating dx/dt=u,dy/dt=v over a time step dt using Improved Euler Integration
                    % up, vp - velocities at positions at beginning of time-step
                    up=interp2(Y,X,u_interp,Yp,Xp);
                    vp=interp2(Y,X,v_interp,Yp,Xp);

                    % First step of Improved Euler is Forward Euler (this is the final position of the velocity data for the entire time window)
                    Xpstar=Xp+up*dt;
                    Ypstar=Yp+vp*dt;

                    % Second step of Improved Euler
                    upstar=interp2(Y,X,u_interp,Ypstar,Xpstar);
                    vpstar=interp2(Y,X,v_interp,Ypstar,Xpstar);

                    % Final positions after each Improved Euler Time Step
                    Xp=Xp+(up+upstar)/2*dt;
                    Yp=Yp+(vp+vpstar)/2*dt;

                end %nn

                % Final lengths based on final coordinates
                a1f        = sqrt((Xp(5)-Xp(1))^2+(Yp(5)-Yp(1))^2);
                a2f        = sqrt((Xp(4)-Xp(1))^2+(Yp(4)-Yp(1))^2);
                b1f        = sqrt((Xp(5)-Xp(2))^2+(Yp(5)-Yp(2))^2);
                b2f        = sqrt((Xp(4)-Xp(3))^2+(Yp(4)-Yp(3))^2);
                c1f        = sqrt((Xp(2)-Xp(1))^2+(Yp(2)-Yp(1))^2);
                c2f        = sqrt((Xp(3)-Xp(1))^2+(Yp(3)-Yp(1))^2);
                d1f        = sqrt((Xp(4)-Xp(2))^2+(Yp(4)-Yp(2))^2);
                d2f        = sqrt((Xp(5)-Xp(3))^2+(Yp(5)-Yp(3))^2);

                % Calculating logarithmic strain rates
                tott       = nt*dt; % Total time for virtual advection
                edot0      = 0.5/tott*(log(a1f/a10)+log(a2f/a10));
                edot45     = 0.5/tott*(log(b1f/b10)+log(b2f/b10));
                edot90     = 0.5/tott*(log(c1f/c10)+log(c2f/c10));
                edot135    = 0.5/tott*(log(d1f/d10)+log(d2f/d10));

                % a legs
                ca         = cosd(alpha);sa=sind(alpha);
                % b legs
                cam45      = cosd(alpha)/sqrt(2)+sind(alpha)/sqrt(2);%cos(alpha-45)
                sam45      = -cosd(alpha)/sqrt(2)+sind(alpha)/sqrt(2);%sin(alpha-45)
                % c legs
                cam90      = sind(alpha);%cos(alpha-90)
                sam90      = -cosd(alpha);%sin(alpha-90)
                % d legs
                cap45      = cosd(alpha)/sqrt(2)-sind(alpha)/sqrt(2);%cos(alpha+45)
                sap45      = cosd(alpha)/sqrt(2)+sind(alpha)/sqrt(2);%sin(alpha+45)
                %
                A          = [ca^2,2*ca*sa,sa^2;cam45^2,2*cam45*sam45,sam45^2;...
                    cam90^2,2*cam90*sam90,sam90^2;cap45^2,2*cap45*sap45,sap45^2];
                lsqmatrix  = inv(A'*A)*A';
                edotvector = lsqmatrix*[edot0;edot45;edot90;edot135];
                
                xpisave(:,mm)       = Xpi;
                ypisave(:,mm)       = Ypi;
                xpsave(:,mm)        = Xp;
                ypsave(:,mm)        = Yp;
                eresults(:,mm)      =...
                                        [edotvector(1),edotvector(2),edotvector(3)]; % Write estimated components into row of eresults

            end %mm each alphas
                ls(jj).eresults(:,:,kk) = eresults;
                ls(jj).xpi(:,:,kk) = xpisave;
                ls(jj).ypi(:,:,kk)  = ypisave;
                ls(jj).xp(:,:,kk) = xpsave;
                ls(jj).yp(:,:,kk) = ypsave;
                ls(jj).lengthscale(kk) = couplinglengthscale(kk);

            %sprintf('Finished with length scale %d out of %d, Moving on to the next lengthscale',kk, length(couplinglengthscale))
        end %kk lengthscales 
            
        progress_perturbations = sprintf('Finished with perturbation %d, Moving on to the next',jj);
        disp(progress_perturbations)            
    end %jj velocity perturbations
            strainrates(ii).vp      = ls;
            strainrates(ii).crossoverROI   = is2roi(ii,:);
            strainrates(ii).crossoverthick = roithick(ii);
            strainrates(ii).roibederror = roibederror(ii);

    progress_xover = sprintf('Finished with crossover %d out of %d, Moving on to the next crossover',ii, length(is2roi));
    disp(progress_xover)
end %ii crossover
```

I've tried using parfor in place of the for loops on a couple occasions, but I can't seem to get it to work properly, in several cases it does not like the way I am saving/indexing my structures, but I'm not sure how to get around that as each structure is formatted such that they can be read into the next more broad structure (e.g. eresults(mm) --> ls(jj) --> strainrates(ii).

Alphas, X/Y, and dt/nt are set before the loop, where alphas rotates every mm loop:
alphas = 0:9:90

Any assistance in helping parallelize or vectorize some of these functions or loops would be greatly appreciated, I'm quite lost when it comes to changing this as its so interconnected. My first thought is that it would either be best to parallelize either the jj loop for numsim, as that loops through 100+ simulations of a montecarlo, or the mm loop for each alpha, as that also seems to take a good few seconds for each loop. Is it better to parallelize the inner loops or the larger outer ones?

Comment: Are you using compiled code? What performance are you getting vs what's your target?

Comment: Maybe you could simplify the code, so we don’t have to deal with this much complexity. A simpler version would have the same loops, but fewer variables and computation. Just enough to demonstrate the issues you were seeing with `parfor`.

Comment: The performance I am getting is extremely slow. It runs through the jj loop (numsim perturbations) every 5-6 minutes. This is a new problem, it used to be much faster, and I don't think I have changed anything internally within those loops to have had it slow down to such an extent. When I have numsim set to 100, this means that it takes ~9 hours to run through a single loop of ii (the outermost loop). This is a new problem, it used to be much faster and would take approximately 1 hour to loop through 100 numsim perturbations. Even that is slow of course, but I can live with that.

Comment: You might want to run a small example (i.e. not the one which takes 9 hours!) with the [profiler enabled](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html), then you can see line-by-line what is causing the slow-down. _Something_ must have changed to cause a 10x slowdown, computers only do what's asked of them...